# LINQ/LAMBDA filter query by date

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I'm trying to use LINQ to SQL to retrieve earnings data for a particular date range.  Currently the table is set up as follows:

```
Comp    Eps    Year    Quarter
IBM     .5     2012    2
IBM     .65    2012    3
IBM     .60    2012    4
IBM     .5     2011    2
IBM     .7     2013    1
IBM     .8     2013    2
```

Except for Eps, all fields have a data type of string or char.  Eps has a data type of double.
Here's my code:

```
var myData = myTable
    .Where(t => t.Comp.Equals("IBM")
        &&
        Convert.Int32(string.Format("{0}{1}", t.Year, t.Quarter)) <= 20131);
```

I get the following error when I tried that:

```
Method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' has no supported translation to SQL
```

How can I select all Eps that has a year & quarter less than "20132" using a lambda expression?

Comment: what is wrong with the current code?

Comment: I think he is using LINQ to SQL which wouldn't support the `string.Format()` method when working on the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to change the database schema, such that `Year` and `Quarter` would become integers.

If that is not possible -- as you say -- you can run half the query in memory by using the `.AsEnumerable()` extension method:

```
var myData =
    myTable.Where(t => t.Comp.Equals("IBM"))
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Where(Convert.Int32(string.Format("{0}{1}", t.Year, t.Quarter)) <= 20131);
```

Depending on how many rows with the same `Comp` you have in your database you will lose some performance though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var myData = myTable
    .Where(t => t.Comp.Equals("IBM")
        && (Convert.ToInt32(t.Year) < 2013 
            || (Convert.ToInt32(t.Year) == 2013 
                && Convert.ToInt32(t.Quarter) <= 2)));
```

Or this:

```
var myData = myTable
    .Where(t => t.Comp.Equals("IBM")
         && String.Compare(t.Year + "" + t.Quarter, "20131") <= 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myData = myTable
    .Where(t => t.Comp.Equals("IBM")
        && (( Convert.ToInt32(t.Year) ==2013 && t.Quarter<2) || Convert.ToInt32(t.Year)<2013 ));
```